# AWS Secrets Manager Resource Policy to Deny all roles Except one Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager, aws-access-policy

I have a secret in secrets manager and there are multiple IAM roles in the system. I only want only one role to access the scecret. Unfortunately there are some other IAM roles that have full Secrets Manager privileges. So i want to restrict the access to the secret to all other roles except desired one by me.

roles

1. IAM_role_that_need_to_access_the_secret.
2. IAM_role_1_that_should_not_access_the_secret.
3. IAM_role_2_that_should_not_access_the_secret.

The following is working.

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::IAM_role_1_that_should_not_access_the_secret",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::IAM_role_2_that_should_not_access_the_secret"
      },
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::IAM_role_that_need_to_access_the_secret"
      },
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "secretsmanager:VersionStage": "AWSCURRENT"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But i want to Deny access to all roles without explicitly mentioning each of them in the Deny permission section. Something like below. But it will restrict to all roles including the desired role.

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::IAM_role_that_need_to_access_the_secret"
      },
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "secretsmanager:VersionStage": "AWSCURRENT"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I asked AWS Support, and they said:

> It is a known issue where `NotPrinicipal` fails the resource policy with an explicit deny.
>
> The workaround is to use `"StringNotEquals":"aws:PrincipalArn"` condition key.

---

**Previous answer:**

<s>You can use [`NotPrincipal`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html)</s>:

```json
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::IAM_role_that_need_to_access_the_secret"
      },
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "*",
      ...
```

Comment: This did not work. Got the following error. An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: User: arn:aws:iam::IAM_role_that_need_to_access_the_secret is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-2:secret:secret-name with an explicit deny

Comment: Oops, I agree! I experimented with it and I keep getting an error that my `assumed-role` (from the IAM Role) is not authorized ... with an explicit deny. It doesn't seem to recognize `NotPrincipal` correctly. Might be worth a call to AWS Support. An alternate approach would be to create another AWS Account, store the secret and only grant `Allow` access to the IAM Role. No need to use Deny since it is in a different account.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [KMS key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/create-keys.html) then create a policy for the KMS key which grants access only to the roles you need. Something like below:

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-default-admin",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow administration of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/<ROLE_NAME>",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/<ROLE_NAME>"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Enable*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Put*",
                "kms:Update*",
                "kms:Revoke*",
                "kms:Disable*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:Delete*",
                "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
                "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/AdminRole",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/<ROLE_NAME>"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Deny use of the key",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/<ROLE_NAME>",
                        "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/<ROLE_NAME>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with using a Condition on the Resource Policy and specifying the ARN of the Role in aws:PrincipalArn (Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-makes-it-easier-to-manage-permissions-for-aws-services-accessing-resources/)

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ 
    {
        "Sid" : "Get",
        "Effect" : "Deny",
        "Principal" : "*",
        "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "Resource" : "<<ARN OF Secret>>",
        "Condition" : {
          "StringNotLike" : {
            "aws:PrincipalArn" : [ 
                "<<ARN of IAM_role_that_need_to_access_the_secret>>" ]
          }
    }
  } ]
}
```